# Appropriate Code Review Posts

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This may be a stupid question with an obvious answer revolving around Code Review.

I'm fully aware there's a [Code Review SE Board](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but from what I've witnessed, the reviews on that board tend towards more mainstream, 'vanilla' languages: Java, C#, PHP etc... I'm using the term 'vanilla' as Apex seems to be a mix of Java & C#, however subjective that might be.

What few Apex questions I've seen on there attract very little attention due to the niché nature of the language leading me to believe the majority of Apex experts exist on the Salesforce Stack Exchange and not the Code Review Stack Exchange.

Given this, is it appropriate to post Code Review questions on the Salesforce Stack Exchange or does this open up a "can of worms", so to speak? When we give advice to, for example, not put queries in `for` loops or to bulkify code is this not, to some extent, Code Review?

I'm interested to know people's thoughts on this or whether the answer is simple "no, if you want Code Review you need to go to the Code Review SE regardless of quantity/quality of response".

Comment: I suspect that most such questions will get closed as `Primarily Opinion Based`. I'm interested to see what others think.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I can appreciate closing on `Primarily Opinion Based`. I'd argue that if a question involved, as a mundane example, removing a query from a `for` loop (something I think we've all seen on SFSE), it's essential to advise removing that as governor limits will in all likelihood get hit, therefore it's an objective fix rather than an opinion and in essence, code review. In this instance, I personally wouldn't expect CRSE users to know anything about Salesforce's governor limits.

Comment: Yeah, what I see as the risk is that someone then posts their 300 LOC method and then asks for code review. Which I might also vote to close as `Too Broad` instead. Maybe if it's an uncommon occurrence it would be worth calling attention to the cross-post here on meta. I'm sure many of us would be happy to take a look in that instance.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You've identified the 'can of worms' I was referring to. ;) There's often a bad habit of posting said 300+ LOC then expecting a Test Class written for it. There is, however, a well-established & understood system to handle that. Perhaps some etiquette on Code Review questions could also be introduced? Or am I just reinventing the wheel here with respect to CRSE? It's just disappointing to see the lack of response to Apex questions on CRSE when I'm sure they'd be attract more abundant, creative answers on SFSE.

Comment: Honestly I lost some interest in CRSE due to the dearth of problems I found interesting. If there were more `Apex`, I would certainly visit more often.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I appreciate that. I'd then say that if a well-versed Apex programmer such as yourself isn't visiting CRSE to begin with, Apex questions on CRSE don't get answered or the response time is too long to the point that weeks, if not months down the line someone might get an answer only to think "oh, I forgot I asked that". Whereas on this, dedicated board, for a niché language, the response time would be low and Apex-educated users would see it. :) Am I making sense? I think it's an interesting discussion anyway but then I did ask the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice is to post your code on CRSE and then try to bring attention to it on the meta here. I think that will be far preferable to posting code review items here, as that type of post is often off topic for our exchange, for a variety of reasons. The `[salesforce-apex]` [tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex) over there only has 8 questions, so you can see why not many of us would check it often.

Comment: I agree with this approach. Code Review questions are very limited in Scope, i.e. they won't highlight or solve a problem that someone else is likely to find useful, even though they may make for interesting reading. I think we should aim to keep them off of the main site for the time being.

Comment: Just to double check I understood correctly, the idea is to post in CRSE, and then open another post on SFmetaSE to draw attention? :)

Comment: Yeah and/or twitter/other channels.